# XML and XSLT creating a menu of links <a href="URL ">Text Description</a> with different url and text

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is what I am after. In standard HTML I can do a list of links like this:

```
<p>
    <a href="/name-of-volume/name-of-book/00-Preamble/Preamble.xml">Preamble</a>
    <a href="/name-of-volume/name-of-book/01-Chapter-01/chapter_1.xml">Chapter 1</a> 
    <a href="/name-of-volume/name-of-book/02-Chapter-02/chapter_2.xml">Chapter 2</a> 
    <a href="/name-of-volume/name-of-book/03-Chapter-03/chapter_3.xml">Chapter 3</a> 
    <a href="/name-of-volume/name-of-book/04-Chapter-04/chapter_4.xml">Chpater 4</a> 
    <a href="/name-of-volume/name-of-book/05-Chapter-05/chapter_5.xml">Chapter 5</a> 
    <a href="/name-of-volume/name-of-book/06-Chapter-06/chapter_6.xml">Chapter 6</a> 
    <a href="/name-of-volume/name-of-book/07-Chapter-07/chapter_7.xml">Chapter 7</a>
    <a href="/name-of-volume/name-of-book/08-Chapter-08/chapter_8.xml">Chapter 8</a> 
    <a href="/name-of-volume/name-of-book/09-Chapter-09/chapter_9.xml">Chapter 9</a> 
    <a href="/name-of-volume/name-of-book/10-Chapter-10/chapter_10.xml">Chapter 10</a> 
    <a href="/name-of-volume/name-of-book/11-Appendix/Appendix.xml">Appendix</a> 
</p>
```

when the browser displays this, the text between the begin and end tags is what appears on the screen as a link, and we do not see the actual URL. When we click the link text, then we jump to the URL.

Using my XML example below (realizing there may be a better setup), how do I set this up (including the XSLT), so that I get the same effect on the browser screen. That is, I want to see the link text, but don't want to display the actual URL.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="/style-sheets/master-rulebook.xsl"?>

<ROOT>

<side_menu_div>
    <link-text>Preamble</link-text>
        <chapter-link>/name-of-volume/name-of-book/00-Preamble/Preamble.xml</chapter-link>
    <link-text>Chapter 1</link-text>
        <chapter-link>/name-of-volume/name-of-book/01-Chapter-01/chapter_1.xml"</chapter-link>
    <link-text>Chapter 2</link-text> 
        <chapter-link>/name-of-volume/name-of-book/02-Chapter-02/chapter_2.xml"></chapter-link>
    <link-text>Chapter 3</link-text> 
        <chapter-link>/name-of-volume/name-of-book/03-Chapter-03/chapter_3.xml"></chapter-link>
    <link-text>Chapter 4</link-text> 
        <chapter-link>/name-of-volume/name-of-book/04-Chapter-04/chapter_4.xml"</chapter-link>
    <link-text>Chapter 5</link-text> 
        <chapter-link>/name-of-volume/name-of-book/05-Chapter-05/chapter_5.xml"</chapter-link>
    <link-text>Chapter 6</link-text> 
        <chapter-link>/name-of-volume/name-of-book/06-Chapter-06/chapter_6.xml"</chapter-link>
    <link-text>Chapter 7</link-text> 
        <chapter-link>/name-of-volume/name-of-book/07-Chapter-07/chapter_7.xml"</chapter-link>
    <link-text>Chapter 8</link-text>
        <chapter-link>/name-of-volume/name-of-book/08-Chapter-08/chapter_8.xml"</chapter-link>
    <link-text>Chapter 9</link-text> 
        <chapter-link>/name-of-volume/name-of-book/09-Chapter-09/chapter_9.xml"</chapter-link>
    <link-text></link-text> 
        <chapter-link>/name-of-volume/name-of-book/10-Chapter-10/chapter_10.xml"Chapter 10</chapter-link>
    <link-text></link-text> 
        <chapter-link>/name-of-volume/name-of-book/11-Appendix/Appendix.xml"Appendix</chapter-link> 
</side_menu_div>

</ROOT>
```

I believe the XML above will work just fine, but it is the XSLT that I have no clue how to set up.

Using the assistance from the poster below, my XSLT now looks like this, and it works nicely

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" >
<xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" />
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />


<xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
        <body style="background-color:#fffc99;  font-size:16pt;">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </body>
    </html>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ROOT">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
</xsl:template>


<xsl:template match="side_menu_div">
    <div style="width: 10%; height: 100%; position: fixed; padding-right: 1em; background: #578be0; " >

        <xsl:for-each select="/ROOT/side_menu_div/link-text">
            <xsl:variable name="index" select="position()" />
                <a href="{/ROOT/side_menu_div/chapter-link[$index]}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </a>
                <br/>
        </xsl:for-each>

    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="chapter">
        <div style="width: 90%; height: auto; position: absolute; margin-left: 10%; padding-left: 1em; background: #fffc99; " >
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </div>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The input XML shared needs some tweaking in order to get the desired output as few `<link-text>` nodes do not have values. Also the `double-quotes` in the `<chapter-link>` are not necessary. Please find below the tweaked input XML.

**Input XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT>
    <side_menu_div>
        <link-text>Preamble</link-text>
        <chapter-link>/name-of-volume/name-of-book/00-Preamble/Preamble.xml</chapter-link>
        <link-text>Chapter 1</link-text>
        <chapter-link>/name-of-volume/name-of-book/01-Chapter-01/chapter_1.xml</chapter-link>
        <link-text>Chapter 2</link-text>
        <chapter-link>/name-of-volume/name-of-book/02-Chapter-02/chapter_2.xml</chapter-link>
        <link-text>Chapter 3</link-text>
        <chapter-link>/name-of-volume/name-of-book/03-Chapter-03/chapter_3.xml</chapter-link>
        <link-text>Chapter 4</link-text>
        <chapter-link>/name-of-volume/name-of-book/04-Chapter-04/chapter_4.xml</chapter-link>
        <link-text>Chapter 5</link-text>
        <chapter-link>/name-of-volume/name-of-book/05-Chapter-05/chapter_5.xml</chapter-link>
        <link-text>Chapter 6</link-text>
        <chapter-link>/name-of-volume/name-of-book/06-Chapter-06/chapter_6.xml</chapter-link>
        <link-text>Chapter 7</link-text>
        <chapter-link>/name-of-volume/name-of-book/07-Chapter-07/chapter_7.xml</chapter-link>
        <link-text>Chapter 8</link-text>
        <chapter-link>/name-of-volume/name-of-book/08-Chapter-08/chapter_8.xml</chapter-link>
        <link-text>Chapter 9</link-text>
        <chapter-link>/name-of-volume/name-of-book/09-Chapter-09/chapter_9.xml</chapter-link>
        <link-text>Chapter  10</link-text>
        <chapter-link>/name-of-volume/name-of-book/10-Chapter-10/chapter_10.xml</chapter-link>
        <link-text>Appendix</link-text>
        <chapter-link>/name-of-volume/name-of-book/11-Appendix/Appendix.xml</chapter-link>
    </side_menu_div>
</ROOT>
```

Following is the XSL that will help in the transformation

**XSL**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
    <xsl:output method="html" encoding="utf-8" />
    <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <p>
            <xsl:for-each select="/ROOT/side_menu_div/link-text">
                <xsl:variable name="index" select="position()" />
                <a href="{/ROOT/side_menu_div/chapter-link[$index]}">
                    <xsl:value-of select="." />
                </a>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: This almost works. I get the menu and the links work, but......... The link text overlaps (spills down) to the next link and each link text is actually opening the link below it. For example the link for chapter 1 is actually opening chapter 2, and the link for chapter 2 opens up chapter 3 and so on. I am going to try post a screen shot so the out put is clear.

Comment: This does actually work. I had to clean up my XML (like you stated above). I still had some trash in the actual code from the real chapters, and had to edit my XSLT to add <br/> tags and some padding and margins. Looks good now and works.